# How do I view the list of Accepted Answered Questions?

Tags: support, search

Pardon the title if it's not clear. I'll explain.

There is an [Unanswered](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered) link for questions that haven't been answered yet.

So, I'm wondering if there is also a link (perhaps hidden) that lets you see questions that have Accepted Answers, meaning the question has been answered, and the answer has been accepted.

This question is probably applicable for all SE sites, not just Android.se

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use some of the advanced search parameters to do this, but I don't think there's a simple link anywhere. The search would be:

```
is:question hasaccepted:yes
```

Which gives you [these results](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+hasaccepted%3Ayes). You can expand the "Advanced Search Tips" link on the right side of the [search page](https://android.stackexchange.com/search) to see other available operators.